# Retrieving elements from a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using `MultipleIterator()` to iterate through two different arrays and get each element.

**My code**

```
$d = new MultipleIterator ();
        $d->attachIterator ( new ArrayIterator ( $tbl_one_data ) );
        $d->attachIterator ( new ArrayIterator ( $tbl_two_data ) );
        foreach ( $d as $data ) {
            print_r($data);
            }
```

Which generates the following :

[image]

My question is how do I loop through the array and return each element? For example I would like to return `2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018`. Tried using `$data[0][0]` but this returns all elements in the first index but I only want one element.

**EDIT**

```
print_r($d);



MultipleIterator Object ( [storage:SplObjectStorage:private] => Array ( [00000000583bd67b000000000ac6c449] => Array ( [obj] => ArrayIterator Object ( [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018 [2] => NONE [3] => NONE ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2014-11-06 11:31:58.799436 [2] => MANAGER [3] => 500 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2014-11-06 11:31:58.841035 [2] => MANAGER [3] => 501 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 2014-11-06 11:33:00.741873 [2] => MANAGER [3] => 500 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 2014-11-06 11:33:00.802389 [2] => MANAGER [3] => 501 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 2014-11-06 13:15:49.457646 [2] => MANAGER [3] => 500 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 2014-11-06 13:37:16.259128 [2] => NONE [3] => NONE ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 2014-11-06 13:37:16.275201 [2] => NONE [3] => 500 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 2014-11-06 13:37:27.682873 [2] => NONE [3] => NONE ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 2014-11-06 13:37:27.690863 [2] => NONE [3] => 500 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 2014-11-06 13:52:21.108003 [2] => MANAGER [3] => 500 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 2014-11-06 14:17:01.266769 [2] => NONE [3] => NONE ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 2014-11-06 14:17:01.279507 [2] => node1-1415283420.0 [3] => 500 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 2014-11-06 14:17:02.527183 [2] => node1-1415283420.0 [3] => 500 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 2014-11-06 14:17:23.775279 [2] => node1-1415283442.1 [3] => 500 ) ) ) [inf] => ) [00000000583bd67a000000000ac6c449] => Array ( [obj] => ArrayIterator Object ( [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => NONE [1] => QUEUESTART [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => ADDMEMBER [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => ADDMEMBER [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => REMOVEMEMBER [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => REMOVEMEMBER [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => ADDMEMBER [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [6] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => PAUSEALL [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [7] => Array ( [0] => Dunc Test [1] => PAUSE [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [8] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => UNPAUSEALL [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [9] => Array ( [0] => Dunc Test [1] => UNPAUSE [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [10] => Array ( [0] => Local/120@disc-agents/n [1] => REMOVEMEMBER [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [11] => Array ( [0] => NONE [1] => QUEUESTART [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [12] => Array ( [0] => NONE [1] => ENTERQUEUE [2] => [3] => 363 [4] => 1 [5] => [6] => ) [13] => Array ( [0] => NONE [1] => ABANDON [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => [6] => ) [14] => Array ( [0] => NONE [1] => ENTERQUEUE [2] => [3] => 363 [4] => 1 [5] => [6] => ) ) ) [inf] => ) ) )
```

Comment: Can you post your orignial array

Comment: @maalls error refferring to index 1.

Comment: @Uchiha which original array? There's two attached..

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r if this is really output by print_r then  $data[0][1]  must be '2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018'

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r both of them

Comment: @Uchiha Well you can see the array output in the picture the first index contains `$tbl_one_data` and the second `$tbl_two_data`

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r put out of print_r($d) as a text, not picture. Let's try to understand what is wrong

Comment: @Uchiha :)  its fine

Comment: @splash58 I have just posted your comment.

Comment: @b0w3rb0w3r I'm not too lazy to play back the data. As i was thinking, $ data [0] [1] in the first array gives what you need, But the second array has a completely different content and even an other structure. No date is  there

Comment: @Uchiha not a problem :)

Comment: @splash58 `$data[0][1]` will get all the second indexed elements in the `[0]` array so it wont check the `[1]` array but there are many `[0]` arrays 15 to be exact so it will return all 15 dates. I just want a way to return one date

Comment: Sorry, I can't see such result. i give up

Comment: I just realised I forgot to mention that the arrays i'm iterating over are also nested.... sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is really output by print_r then $data[0][1] must be '2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018' . I test it by code:

```
$data = array(array('1','2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data); echo '<br>';
echo 'what we want: '.$data[0][1].'<br>';
```

otput:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018
        )

)

what we want: 2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018
```

Comment: What if you have multiple arrays? I have 15 arrays each containing 2 arrays in the structure shown on the picture of the OP. If I use `$data[0][1]` the output is :
`2014-11-06 11:31:58.7810182014-11-06 11:31:58.7994362014-11-06 11:31:58.8410352014-11-06 11:33:00.7418732014-11-06 11:33:00.8023892014-11-06 13:15:49.4576462014-11-06 13:37:16.2591282014-11-06 13:37:16.2752012014-11-06 13:37:27.6828732014-11-06 13:37:27.6908632014-11-06 13:52:21.1080032014-11-06 14:17:01.2667692014-11-06 14:17:01.2795072014-11-06 14:17:02.5271832014-11-06 14:17:23.775279`

Comment: ok. put out of print_r($d) as a text, not picture. Let's try to understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you have the $data as an array you can access the value: 2014-11-06 11:31:58.781018 by using,

```
$date = $data[0][1];
```

Comment: No I can't I have explained this in the question.